# syslog filling up with the below error trace while gaming

Tags: kernel, games, disk-usage, syslog

System:

- 5.4.0-39-generic #43-Ubuntu
- AMD Ryzen 7
- AMD 6600XT
- 32GB RAM
- ASUS B450 Plus

---

Background:

I have been running this Ryzen 7 and same board with an Nvidia 970 in Fedora 31 without issues.  When I bought the AMD 6600XT about 4 days ago, Fedora driver support by AMD is not being offered so I installed Ubuntu 20.  This is a new install with newly updated kernel and newest AMD drivers.  I have been using this setup for the last 3 days without issue.  My guess is that it took roughly 3 days for my issue to occur.

---

Issue:

I was playing an older game in with Proton and I got a system alert stating I was almost out of hard drive space.  I checked the volume and saw my syslog was over 100GB and the concatted file was over 45GB.  I cleared my logs to save up space and watched my syslog file as I went back to gaming.  I kept seeing this error over and over.  The harder my system churned, the more I got the following:

```
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262472] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262594] WARNING: CPU: 8 PID: 1804 at /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.13-1089974/build/amd/amdgpu/../display/dc/dcn20/dcn20_hwseq.c:129 dcn20_setup_gsl_group_as_lock+0x82/0x200 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262598] Modules linked in: rpcsec_gss_krb5 auth_rpcgss nfsv4 nfs lockd grace fscache binfmt_misc edac_mce_amd kvm_amd kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi amdgpu(OE) snd_hda_intel nls_iso8859_1 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_core mc amd_iommu_v2 snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul amd_sched(OE) amdttm(OE) snd_pcm snd_seq_midi ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_seq amdkcl(OE) snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper snd_timer eeepc_wmi joydev input_leds asus_wmi i2c_algo_bit sparse_keymap fb_sys_fops video syscopyarea snd sysfillrect wmi_bmof sysimgblt k10temp soundcore ccp mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm sunrpc ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul i2c_piix4 r8169 nvme ahci realtek libahci nvme_core wmi gpio_amdpt gpio_generic
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262668] CPU: 8 PID: 1804 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W  OE     5.4.0-39-generic #43-Ubuntu
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262669] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/PRIME B450-PLUS, BIOS 0409 08/24/2018
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262780] RIP: 0010:dcn20_setup_gsl_group_as_lock+0x82/0x200 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262785] Code: 74 48 84 c0 75 26 48 8b 87 30 03 00 00 0f b6 80 70 02 00 00 a8 01 0f 84 dc 00 00 00 a8 02 74 56 a8 04 0f 84 f7 00 00 00 0f 0b <0f> 0b 48 8b 45 e0 65 48 33 04 25 28 00 00 00 0f 85 56 01 00 00 48
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262789] RSP: 0018:ffffb5c182667590 EFLAGS: 00010202
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262793] RAX: 0000000000000007 RBX: ffff9c99a8ea01b8 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262796] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff9c99a8ea01b8 RDI: ffff9c9a761a0000
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262800] RBP: ffffb5c1826675d8 R08: ffffb5c18266758c R09: ffffb5c182667550
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262803] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000002 R12: 0000000000000001
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262808] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffff9c9a761a0000 R15: ffff9c99a8ea01b8
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262812] FS:  00007f552df11a80(0000) GS:ffff9c9a7ee00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262815] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262818] CR2: 00003f001ae59000 CR3: 00000007a696e000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262821] Call Trace:
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.262933]  dcn20_pipe_control_lock+0x1d1/0x1e0 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263034]  dc_stream_set_cursor_position+0x128/0x160 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263149]  handle_cursor_update.isra.0+0x1af/0x2f0 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263256]  amdgpu_dm_commit_cursors.isra.0+0x60/0x80 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263368]  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail+0x13b6/0x20b0 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263474]  ? amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail+0x1684/0x20b0 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263481]  ? amdttm_bo_validate+0x54/0x180 [amdttm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263484]  ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x173/0x320
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263487]  ? native_apic_wait_icr_idle+0x22/0x30
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263489]  ? arch_irq_work_raise+0x3a/0x40
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263491]  ? sched_clock+0x9/0x10
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263494]  ? dbs_update_util_handler+0x1b/0x80
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263567]  ? amdgpu_vm_del_from_lru_notify+0x12/0x70 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263572]  ? ttm_bo_del_from_lru+0x8e/0xa0 [amdttm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263578]  ? amdttm_bo_move_to_lru_tail+0x2d/0xc0 [amdttm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263580]  ? ww_mutex_unlock+0x26/0x30
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263585]  ? amdttm_eu_backoff_reservation+0x49/0x70 [amdttm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263658]  ? amdgpu_bo_gpu_offset+0x27/0xb0 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263765]  ? dm_plane_helper_prepare_fb+0x14b/0x290 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263770]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263771]  ? wait_for_completion_timeout+0x3a/0x120
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263773]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263774]  ? wait_for_completion_interruptible+0x37/0x160
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263784]  commit_tail+0x99/0x110 [drm_kms_helper]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263794]  drm_atomic_helper_commit+0x118/0x120 [drm_kms_helper]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263900]  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit+0x95/0xa0 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263916]  drm_atomic_commit+0x4a/0x50 [drm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263926]  drm_atomic_helper_update_plane+0xea/0x100 [drm_kms_helper]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263945]  __setplane_atomic+0xcc/0x110 [drm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263962]  drm_mode_cursor_universal+0x13e/0x260 [drm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263978]  drm_mode_cursor_common+0xcc/0x220 [drm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.263996]  ? drm_mode_cursor_ioctl+0x60/0x60 [drm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264012]  drm_mode_cursor2_ioctl+0xe/0x10 [drm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264024]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xae/0xf0 [drm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264039]  drm_ioctl+0x234/0x3d0 [drm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264056]  ? drm_mode_cursor_ioctl+0x60/0x60 [drm]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264059]  ? ___sys_recvmsg+0x88/0xc0
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264133]  amdgpu_drm_ioctl+0x4e/0x80 [amdgpu]
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264135]  do_vfs_ioctl+0x407/0x670
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264138]  ? fput+0x13/0x15
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264141]  ? __sys_recvmsg+0x88/0xa0
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264143]  ksys_ioctl+0x67/0x90
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264145]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x1a/0x20
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264147]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264149]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264151] RIP: 0033:0x7f552e26f37b
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264153] Code: 0f 1e fa 48 8b 05 15 3b 0d 00 64 c7 00 26 00 00 00 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff c3 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d e5 3a 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264155] RSP: 002b:00007ffe434074c8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264157] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffe43407560 RCX: 00007f552e26f37b
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264158] RDX: 00007ffe43407560 RSI: 00000000c02464bb RDI: 000000000000000c
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264158] RBP: 00000000c02464bb R08: 000000000000042f R09: 00007ffe434075b0
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264159] R10: 000000000000007f R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055db5207be30
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264160] R13: 000000000000000c R14: 000055db51dc6f70 R15: 000000000000033a
Jun 29 22:01:13 ANS-PRIME kernel: [ 1809.264163] ---[ end trace d823149b05451c00 ]---
```

---

Replication:
I am able to replicate this with any game that activates the display, including Linux games not using wine, thus, I don't believe it is a wine issue.

Edit:
Removed the side note, unrelated

---

Question:

Is this a known spam that can be turned off or something indicative of a more serious issue?  The rig seems to be operating fine, just need to get the system log issue sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

ASUS PRIME B450-PLUS

You have BIOS 0409 08/24/2018

There's a newer BIOS available which may solve your problem. BIOS 2008, dated 12/11/2019, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B450-PLUS/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS

**Update #1:**

It's been reported that there may be possible compatibility issues with certain Ryzen processors, certain SSDs, and certain overclocked memory DIMMs, and the 2008 BIOS.

- Assure that you have the latest firmware in your Intel SSDs. See https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/134583
- Ryzen CPUs are a bit fussy about RAM compatibility anyway. See https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B450-PLUS/HelpDesk_QVL/ for the list of compatible RAM.
- Different Ryzen CPU models can limit the maximum overclocked RAM speeds. See https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B450-PLUS/HelpDesk_CPU/

[image]

**Update #2:**

I'd also recommend checking your AMDGPU driver for updates, as that's what crashed.

Comment: I actually updated my BIOS instinctively after posting this, so the following commentary is not directed at you:  This is terrible advice.  BIOS 2008 completely broke my system.  2008 broke compatibility with my Intel SSD7 256GB and I can no longer run my memory on its native 3200MHz mode.  I cannot downgrade back to a Zen1 BIOS, I had to downgrade to a Zen2 BIOS at 1201 just so I could boot to my Intel drive.  I still cannot boot up with 3200MHz memory speed.

Comment: Additionally, I am still getting the same problem with BIOS 1201.

Comment: I just put 2008 back on the system.  Support had me try various configuration options and I was able to boot back into Ubuntu.  I am no longer getting the syslog spam, HOWEVER, I lost compatibility with 3200MHz RAM speed.  My RAM supports 3200MHz but the board will no longer function with the memory running at this speed.  There are known issues with this motherboard and compatibility with some hardware, so if you put an advisory warning ASUS motherboard users to properly research Zen2 BIOS breaking SSD and memory compatibility, then I will accept your recommendation.

Comment: @StuartAnderson Sorry to hear about your difficulties. I've updated my answer. I'd also recommend checking your AMD driver for updates, as that's what crashed. Please remember to accept my answer, as it solved your original question. Thanks!